# JS: Why do you not return inner function with `function` word around it?

Tags: javascript, closures

If I am making a factory function `foo`, why do I not return the inner function as `function noiseMade()` rather than just `noiseMade()` ?

```
function foo() {
    let sound = "buzz"
    return {

        noiseMade() {

            return "I make" + sound
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It's returning an object with "noiseMade" as the name of a property. The value of that property is the function. It's ES2015 object initializer syntax.

Comment: You can do `{ noiseMade: function()...}` or `{ noiseMade() {}}`, the second syntax was added in es6.

Comment: @Papi but why wouldn't `function noiseMade()` work?

Comment: @JohnNada Because this syntax is not supported :)

Comment: ha, fair enough!  Thanks @papi

Comment: @JohnNada You could i.e. just return a function instead of an object if you prefer `function() {}` syntax if you don't need any other values to be exported

Comment: @Papi I tried that with this: return `{ function() { console.log("test" ) }` .   Then I set `a = foo()` and tried to run `a()`, and it states a is not a function

Comment: @JohnNada remove curly braces and return just a function. Like `return function() {}` :)

Comment: thanks again @Papi

Comment: @JohnNada If you want to return an object, you can't use this syntax unfortunately :{

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sum up our conversation from the comments.
Supported syntax for functions in objects:

```
{
  makeNoise: function() {}
}

// ES6 and above
{
  makeNoise() {},
  makeAnotherNoise: () => {} // behave a bit different, read about arrow functions for more info
}
```

If you want to return a function from another function you could i.e.:

```
const makeNoise = () => {
  const sound = 'bork';
  return () => { console.log(sound) };
}
```

Also one additional free comment :) It's preferred to use `verbs` for functions names, because functions usually `do` stuff :)

Comment: right on, thanks for making an `answer` rather than comment so I could select your as the correct √

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you have mentioned:

```
const obj = {
  propertyName() { ... }
};
```

is a [shorthand method declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Method_definitions) introduced in ES6

It is equivalent to a classic declaration:

```
const obj = {
  propertyName: function fnName() { ... }
};
```